# Missing documentation for Qt5 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I use Qt Creator for building applications and recently I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 and upgrade my current project from Qt4 to Qt5. The problem is that the Help section provides no documentation for Qt5. For Qt4 I used to have the package `qt4-doc`, but there's no `qt5-doc` or anything similar.

How to install the Qt5 documentation?

Comment: There isn't a qt5-doc package for Ubuntu yet but everything is available [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/index.html) . From what I understand though the jump from Qt4 to Qt5 isn't that massively drastic, so you could even just use qt4-doc for the moment

Comment: Or you take the newest documentation that comes with the official installer from [qt-project](http://www.qt-project.org). You find a download link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a qt5-doc package, but it is on a separate repository.

To install it, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc
```

Then you must declare it in Qt Assistant:

```
Edit => Preferences => Documentation => Add
```

and then select file

```
/usr/share/qt5/doc/qch/qtdoc.qch
```

Yes, Qt5 integration in Ubuntu seems to be half baked.

Best,

Comment: I've done that but something must be missing since searching for something basic like `QThread` turns up no results.

Comment: That's correct, and the "All classes" page does not list any class. I agree something must be missing from my "solution" above.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the official Ubuntu-documentation for Qt5 is very incomplete. You don't have information about nearly any class.

If you want to use the QtCreator build from Ubuntu you have to acquire the docs yourself. I did and uploaded these on my personal Mega-account. Here are the [docs](https://mega.co.nz/#F!IEQViZBD!IH66QnC6nus5tKn7Sh7Usw).
I installed the Qt framework with the installer from qt-project.org, grabbed the documentation and inserted it into the software-center-version.

To add the docs to QtCreator go to Tools>Options>Help>Documentation and click add. Then select all .qch files, click apply and enjoy your new help.